# How could I write sub-query with right join in cakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to write sub-query with right join of sql in cake php , query below

```
SELECT stkid,s.id as stk_id, s.userid as stk_userid,
       s.productid as productid, u.id as userid
FROM (select * FROM stocks as st where st.`productid` = 1) as s
  right join users as u on (u.id = s.userid)
group by u.id
```

please help me out with this 
any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Most people find right join too confusing. (Left join is hard enough...) That's why I always do LEFT JOIN instead. (I.e. switch both join type and left/right side tables.)

Comment: Did you try answer from this post? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497923/how-to-write-sql-query-in-cakephp

Comment: Rulisp No above post won't work for me

Comment: jarlh i am very much comfortable with right join and i have wrote right join query in cakephp but stuck with sub-query :(

Comment: How about something like [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements)?

Comment: @NeerajRathod, don't get me wrong, I didn't say your right join were wrong, I just said most people prefer left join. And perhaps someone else will need to read, understand and adjust your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to say your SQL query is not optimised : your FROM sub-query is useless.

Take a look :

```
SELECT 
    stkid, 
    s.id AS stk_id, 
    s.userid AS stk_userid,
    s.productid AS productid, 
    u.id AS userid
FROM stocks AS s 
RIGHT JOIN users AS u 
    ON u.id = s.userid
WHERE s.productid = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```

---

### Direct SQL

The "I just want the answer of this sql", and the simple way is this (in controller) :

```
    // get the DB link
$pdo = $this->ModelOfThisController->getDataSource()->getConnection();

$sql = "SELECT 
            stkid, 
            s.id AS stk_id, 
            s.userid AS stk_userid,
            s.productid AS productid, 
            u.id AS userid
        FROM (
            SELECT * 
            FROM stocks AS st 
            WHERE st.`productid` = 1
            ) AS s
        RIGHT JOIN users AS u 
            ON (u.id = s.userid)
        GROUP BY u.id
    ";


$req = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$req->execute(array(
    // ':param1' => $param1,
    // ':param2' => $param2,
    ));

$data = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // ...
```

---

### ORM

The other way is [with cakePHP ORM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries) but I don't think you can change the FROM to anything else than the models' table name...